# Java math question, outcome different!

Tags: java, math

Why are the outcomes different for first and first1?  I'm guessing it has to do with the limit for the Long type.

```
long seconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
long first = (seconds / (1000*60*60*24))/365;
long first1 = seconds / (1000*60*60*24*365);
System.out.println(first); 
System.out.println(first1);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The denominator of the second one overflows the `int` type.

No difference if you do it like this - use long throughout:

```
public class Overflow
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long seconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long first = (seconds / (1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L)) / 365L;
        long i = 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L * 365L;
        long first1;
        first1 = seconds / i;
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.println(first);
        System.out.println(first1);
        System.out.println(first1/first);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to give the answer to this one because your example showed me something new (L suffix) that I didn't know.  Thank you!

Comment: @Steve, this is the correct answer.  Integer division does change the result, but not enough to affect the final truncated value in this case.  The overflow (which I missed before) is the real issue.

Comment: This is interesting...so if the value I type is too large for integer, it gets truncated when in division, but the overflow in the 2nd one maxes out the integer?

Comment: Or for shorter; long i = 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365; Only the first expression needs to be long.

Answer (score 10):

Its because in the first one you dividing by an int, which gets truncated and then dividing by another int.

In the second one, you are just dividing by an int.